# CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME is always returning null for some saved contacts

Tags: java, android, calllog

I am trying to show the call log details in my app but CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME is always returning null for some contacts even if it is a saved contact with name. The built-in call log is showing the names for these contacts correctly.

This is my code:

```
protected customAdapRecent doInBackground(Void... params) {

        ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
        final String[] PROJECTION = new String[] {
                                               //     CallLog.Calls.CACHED_LOOKUP_URI,
                                                    CallLog.Calls.NUMBER,
                                                    CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME,
                                                    CallLog.Calls.TYPE,
                                                    CallLog.Calls.DATE,
                                                    CallLog.Calls.DURATION
                                                };

        Cursor cursor = resolver.query(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, PROJECTION, null, null, CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC");
        if(cursor.getCount() > 0)
        {
            int iNumber = cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
            int iName = cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME);
            int iType = cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE);
            int iDate = cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE);
            int iDuration = cursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION);

            DateFormat datePattern = DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.FULL);

            String number;
            String name;
            String type;
            String date;
            String duration;
            String contactId;
            String callIs = "None";
            String prevDate = "";
            int callType;


            while (cursor.moveToNext())
            {

                if(cursor.getString(iName) == null)
                    Log.e("DEBUG: ", "Position: " + cursor.getPosition());

                number = cursor.getString(iNumber);
                name = cursor.getString(iName);
                type = cursor.getString(iType);
                String tempdate = cursor.getString(iDate);
                Long tempDate = Long.parseLong(tempdate);
                date = datePattern.format(tempDate);

                if(prevDate.equalsIgnoreCase(date))
                {
                    prevDate = date;
                    date = "";
                }
                else
                    prevDate = date;
                //date = new Date(Long.valueOf(strdate));
                duration = cursor.getString(iDuration);
                callType = Integer.parseInt(type);
                switch (callType)
                {
                    case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
                        callIs = "OUT";
                        recentRow newRowO = new recentRow(number, name, date, duration, callIs);
                        listItem_recentOut.add(newRowO);
                        break;

                    case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
                        callIs = "IN";
                        recentRow newRowI = new recentRow(number, name, date, duration, callIs);
                        listItem_recentIn.add(newRowI);
                        break;

                    case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
                        callIs = "MISS";
                        recentRow newRowM = new recentRow(number, name, date, duration, callIs);
                        listItem_recentMiss.add(newRowM);
                        break;

                }

                recentRow newRow = new recentRow(number, name, date, duration, callIs);
                //recentRow newRow = new recentRow(number, name, callIs);
                listItem_recentAll.add(newRow);
            }
            cursor.close();
            cAdapRecent = new customAdapRecent(context, listItem_recentAll);
        }

        return cAdapRecent;
    }
```

The Debug statement given in the Log.e() is also printing.

Am I doing something wrong in the lookup? Pls. suggest a way as I am really blocked due to this!

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Were those people in your contacts at the time that the call was made? The point of `CACHED_NAME` is to hold what was known at the time of the call.

Comment: Yes, those are saved contacts with Name.. And the Android built-in app it is showing the name.

Comment: "those are saved contacts with Name" -- that is not what I asked. "And the Android built-in app it is showing the name" -- it may be looking up the value in `ContactsContract`.

Comment: Yes those contacts were there in my contacts when the call was made.

Comment: I am getting same problem when i make a call, after call end i get the updated list of call logs but i am getting null value for name, did you get the answer?

Comment: I am also facing same issue. Any solution you got? Please share.

Comment: @PeterB check my workaround below

Answer (score 5):

I also came across this strange behavior and figured out that sometimes you can't get name of the contact immediately even though you can get everything else from the `CallLog.Calls`. What I noticed is that after approximately one hour or so since that call you can fetch name along with all other `CallLog.Calls` data. Very strange. If you need immediate refresh after call you can get name for the number from `ContactsContract` like this:

```
 fun getNameForNumber(context: Context, number: String): String? {

        var res: String? = null
        try {
            val resolver = context.contentResolver
            val uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(number))
            val c = resolver.query(uri, arrayOf(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME), null, null, null)

            if (c != null) {
                if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                    res = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME))
                }
                c.close()
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

        return res
    }
```

Strangely, after you fetch one name from the `ContactsContract` fetching name in the way you did it, through CallLog.Calls.CACHED_NAME, misteriously works.

This is also answer for @PeterB and @shyam002